# Linux command Cat dont file archive but archive in folder

Tags: linux, shell, file, cat

When I try to `cat` in one file, for exemple `cert.pem` I receive ab error: No such file or directory

[image: my folder and command]

Comment: The red colour is because the destination of the link does not exist.

Comment: thanks, i gone back the original folder and found the original files by link

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Sorry dude, I did not think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are symbolic links - special files that just contain the path to another file. When you `cat` them, they essentially redirect to the file they link to. However, as evident by the red color in the `ls` output, these links are broken - they point to files that do not exist, and thus you get that error when you try to `cat` them.

Comment: Thanks guy, i did not know they were links.

Comment: Great work for answering off-topics.